# AWS S3 bucket organization access policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My company has an organization set up in AWS (CompanyA as example). Each team has an account joined to this organization (HR, ProductA, ProductB, ect..).  We in ProductA are attempting to grant read-only access to an S3 bucket which serves as a yum repository we own to anyone under this organization from their ec2 instance without auth (yum commands works out of box)

Some items we evaluated:
https://github.com/rmela/yum-s3-plugin -> This would go along with user principal access, users would need to add their keys to pull from the repo

http://parthicloud.com/how-to-access-s3-bucket-from-application-on-amazon-ec2-without-access-credentials/ -> Great tutorial for inside your own account, ec2 instances need to be brought up with a IAM policy to allow access to bucket.

Answer (score 27):

Add a condition to the bucket policy listing your AWS Organization, and allow all principals access. See [AWS Global Condition Context Keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html), search for `aws:PrincipalOrgID`. "When you add and remove accounts, policies that include `aws:PrincipalOrgID` automatically include the correct accounts and don't require manual updating."

The `Action` and `Resource` sections in the example below should be the same as for your current policy that lists all the AWS accounts in your organization.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Sid": "AllowOrganizationToReadYumBucket",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": [
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:ListBucket"
    ],
    "Resource": [
      "arn:aws:s3:::your-yum-bucket",
      "arn:aws:s3:::your-yum-bucket/*"
    ],
    "Condition": {
      "StringEquals": {"aws:PrincipalOrgID":["o-xxxxxxxxxxx"]}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution. The only problem is that the `s3:ListObject` permission does not exist. It should be `s3:ListBucket`

Comment: This allows permissions to all account users, groups, roles in all the accounts.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible for an Amazon S3 bucket policy to refer to a group of accounts in an *AWS Organization*.

Your bucket policy would need to list permissions for each account individually. For example:

```
"Principal":{"AWS":"arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-NUMBER:user/*"}
```

Comment: Yeah, we have that working.  I should probaly describe this a bit more too.  This S3 repo will be a yum repository.  We were hoping to be able to add some polices to allow other accounts access to the repository without login on their ec2 instances.  I've found tons of examples that work within own account (http://parthicloud.com/how-to-access-s3-bucket-from-application-on-amazon-ec2-without-access-credentials/) and ones that require s3 auth with yum (https://github.com/rmela/yum-s3-plugin).